# Effectively immutable array-backed sequence with linear concatenation and appending

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sequence, fold

Probably most courses of algorithm and data structures include a growable array buffer with amortized cost O(1) for appending an element by growing the underlying array by a factor. In imperative languages, it is often the most efficient implementation of a list.

Array-backed sequences still have a lot of advantages even when immutable, but in functional languages a loop appending repeatedly to a buffer is typically replaced with a fold:

```
//imperative pattern:
val buffer = new ArrayBuffer
for (list <- lists) {
    buffer append list
}

//functional pattern:
foldLeft(Nil)( (acc, list) => list :::acc)(lists)
```

Which works fine with linked lists, but in naive implementation has O(n^n) cost with arrays. It is however possible to adapt the trick of the growing buffer to implement an effectively immutable data structure:

```
class ArrayList {
    val array :Array
    val firstIndex :Int
    val length :Int
    var ownsPrefix :Boolean
    var ownsSuffix :Boolean
}
```

So, while every instance of `ArrayList` would represent a constant section of an array `firstIndex .. firstIndex+length`, which is guaranteed not to change contents within that section, but can be shared between several instances.
Additional mutable flags `ownsPrefix`, `ownsSuffix` define if the instance is free to change contents of the elements of the array before the first/after the last element (corresponding sections of the array aren't used by any structure). If so, and there is enough space available, than concatenation operation will simply copy the elements of appended/prepended list to the proper fragment of the buffer, switch off the corresponding flag, and return a value representing the combined section of the array, *which now owns the buffer*.

It's a simple trick which solves a problem with the most popular use case of repeated growing of a single structure, but I haven't seen it actually implemented in any standard or popular library.

My question is: does it have a name, has it been analized, or does it have efficient open source implementations out there? I have implemented it in scala for my own use and would like to open source it, but would hate to reinvent the wheel and would gladly incorporate any tweaks and optimisation already invented for it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen such a thing, but maybe finger trees fill a similar need.

TurinArrayList:

- O(n) storage
- O(1) indexing
- amortized O(1) append/prepend
- O(n) concatenation

Finger tree:

- O(n) storage
- O(log m) indexing, where m is the distance from the beginning or end
  e.g. O(1) to retrieve the first or last
- amortized O(1) append/prepend
- amortized O(log n) concatenation

Finger trees also have better sharing. For example, `fingerTree`, `fingerTree :+ 1`, and `fingerTree :+ 2` will (on average) share most of their storage, as opposed to your design where `arrayList`, `arrayList :+ 1`, and `arrayList :+ 2` will always copy at least one full array, if I'm understanding your description of it correctly.

On the upside, you should have a much simpler implementation, true constant-time random access, and CPU cache-friendly contiguous memory layout.

Comment: I'll look them up, but they sound a bit similar to Tries. While there are much more versatile structures in general, this case was about doing one thing well; iteration and indexing ofer arrays are about as memory and time efficient as it gets, and the goal here wasn't efficient concatenation in general, but taking advantage of a typical usage pattern to provide efficient building of the sequence without going through an intermediate step for the lazy me (let he who never concatenated strings that way first throw the stone).

Comment: I don't see similarity between tries and finger trees, except for having variable fan-out at each node. Finger trees are structurally similar to B-trees, with the addition of "fingers" that provide quick access to the first and last elements, and some different balancing rules.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this specific idea, but it's related to [uniqueness typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type), a way to specify in the type system that it's safe to mutate a value, and to [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), which uses reference counting to defer the work of copying a value to mutate it.